# View Composers vs Blade Service Injection in Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-blade

What's the difference between View Composers and Blade Service Injection in Laravel 5.4???

Which one to use and why?

Answer (score 1):

Blade Service Injection makes it so you can inject a service straight into a **single** view. View composers can make that service available to **ALL** your views.

If you are only using a service once, go with the blade @inject directive. If you need your service in every view, go with view composers

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I didn't explain may case, I'm including a menu in all my layouts I wasn't sure which one is recommended for my case. I wanna make just one variable(a collection in this case) available site-wide and that menu uses the @include and both variants work. Just wanted to know which one is best an why.

Comment: In your case, you would want to use the View::share() method (https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/views#sharing-data-with-all-views ) to share a collection with all views. Or you can use View Composers to call a service that has a method that returns your collection. Blade Service Injection doesn’t make sense for you as you need it all views, not just one.